# Laravel Eloquent model duplicate keys in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I cannot figure out what is the problem, I cannot remember when it firstly appeared, it doesn't make a lot of problems now, but it wastes connection and this is not last point in mobile communication. 
The problem is following.

Here is output of model, such output is for any model, I mean it duplicates each associative value with index.

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:12 [
    "id" => "55"
    0 => "55"
    "user_id" => "199"
    1 => "199"
    "token" => "b7351fb13c5ce06a6f09ef6147c7d7d5"
    2 => "b7351fb13c5ce06a6f09ef6147c7d7d5"
    "expiration_time" => "1452795403"
    3 => "1452795403"
    "scope" => "0"
    4 => "0"
    "last_login_time" => "1452194400"
    5 => "1452194400"
  ]
]
```

I have tried to follow the stack of function call and stopped at

```
public static function hydrate(array $items, $connection = null)
```

The I got here dump as I described above.

I have no idea what can cause such behavior.

Maybe someone has idea what can cause such problem. 
Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**

I have uploaded code to pastebin http://laravel.io/bin/VP435

I edited model for my needs, but it shouldn't affect this part.

I am trying to find the "root of evil" right now.

`hybrate` method is called by `Builder`

```
public function getModels($columns = ['*'])
```

This is query to DB 
       $results = $this->query->get($columns);

Query is following

```
"select * from `tokens` where `token` = ? limit 1"
```

And it is correct request no issue with it

Comment: Would you [pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin) the code of your Model ? Which version of Laravel are you running, exactly?

Comment: I've just updated, please see post edit

Comment: You pasted the Model class of the Laravel framework. But how is your model called, and which is it's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that in `config/database.php` you have set `fetch` to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and not to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

By default it's `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and it seems you have somehow set it to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

If it's not the case, show example how you get this object.

Comment: AWESOME !! I have just found by myself that `$me->getFetchMode()` returns null and set it by default as `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` , it was missing in database config file ! But than saw you answer and did everything correctly !
Thanks for answer, have a nice day !